# Multithreading: passing instance and local variables to a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a doubt about passing instance and local variables as parameters to a thread.

Let me show you a brief example:

```
public class Foo {
    private int num;
    private String str;

    public Foo(int num, String str){
        this.num = num;
        this.str = str;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }
}


public class FooRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Foo foo;

    public FooRunnable(Foo foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Number =" +foo.num);
        System.out.println("String =" +foo.str);    
    }
}

public class Test {

private Foo fooField;

public Test(){
    fooField = new Foo(4, "four");
}

public void launchField(){
    Thread th = new Thread(new FooRunnable(fooField));
    th.start();
}

public void launchLocalVariable(){
    Foo fooLocal = new Foo(5,  "five");
    Thread th = new Thread(new FooRunnable(fooLocal));
    th.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test =  new Test();
    test.launchField();
    test.launchLocalVariable();
}
```

}

It's just a stupid program that launches two threads: one passing an instance variable as parameter to thread and other passing a local variable. Later, both threads write the content from the passed parameters to console.

In the case of the local variable i'm sure that its behaviour is thread-safe. In the second case, i think it doesn't, due to possible caching of that variable. What do you think about it? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple: if information can be changed by threads, you always have to worry about thread-safety.

The important part is: ability to be changed.

In your example, the fields of Foo are readonly. There is no way to change them after the Foo object was created. Because of that, any usage of any Foo object is thread safe. Even when you give the same Foo object to 10 different threads; they will always see the same data.

This property of a class is called immutability; and you can make that even more explicit by using the final keyword for the two fields within Foo. Simply spoken: if you can design all your classes to be immutable, there is much less to worry regarding thread safety.

But if there would be setters on Foo enabling others to change the fields upon creation of a Foo object; then "local" versus field would indeed make a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Jägermeister, i understand it. But, in the case I had defined setters for the Foo class and assigned values using it, which case would be thread safe? I think just "local" sample would be fully thread-safe, isn't it?

Comment: I think I told you what to need to know. The point: if any other thread is able to change the object, then you have a potential problem. Weird example: assume that your class Foo had static fields ... then it wouldn't matter where the Foo object is created. And keep in mind: in reality, your objects do need "context". It is great if you can just create a "local variable" and nobody else has access to that. But you will find pretty soon that this will restrict you in other ways. So "generating everything" local is a good policy, but you will not always be able to achieve it!